# Intersection Area of 'n' shapefiles - Python

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

I have 'n' shapefiles and where they intersect i need to sum a specific attribute. In some points they all intersects, in other points only some of them intersects while in others i don't have any intersection. My final results would be a single shapefile (union of the 'n' shapefiles') where for each intersection area i get the sum of a specific attribute. Is there an easy way to do it, without converting to raster? I already tried with the Geopandas "Overlay" function but without iterating many times i can only get the area where all the shapefiles intersect and not where only some of them intersect.

you can find the shapefiles here: http://www.mediafire.com/folder/2ckfxkfda0asm/shapes

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
g1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("shape1.shp")
g2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("shape2.shp")
g3 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("shape3.shp")
g1['number'] = pd.to_numeric(g1['number'])
g2['number'] = pd.to_numeric(g2['number'])
g3['number'] = pd.to_numeric(g3['number'])
df = pd.concat([g1,g2,g3])
intersection = g1
simmetric = g1
lista = [g2,g3]
for i in lista:
    intersection = gpd.overlay(intersection, i, how='intersection').fillna(0)
    intersection.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(intersection.index))
    intersection.loc[:,'number'] = intersection.loc[:,'number_1'].add(intersection.loc[:,'number_2'])
    intersection.drop(["number_1", "number_2"], axis = 1, inplace = True) 
    simmetric = gpd.overlay(simmetric, i, how='symmetric_difference').fillna(0)
    simmetric.loc[:,'number'] = simmetric.loc[:,'number_1'].add(simmetric.loc[:,'number_2'])
    simmetric.drop(["number_1", "number_2"], axis = 1, inplace = True)     
final_result = pd.concat([simmetric,intersection])
final_result.to_file("result.shp")
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRBts.jpg)

Comment: Please, upload the code you have tried.

Comment: Could you add enough code and examples to show what you have tried? As it is now, your question is hard to answer as we're left with no sources to start from. Perhaps it is easier to start with an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I see how you could sum the area of the intersections, but why would you need to create an intersected geometry if all you need to do is sum of the attributes?

Comment: How could i sum the attributes when the shapefiles intersect without converting it to a raster?

Comment: I just need to sum the attributes of those 3 shapefiles in the intersection areas. WIth the code i posted before, i am only able to perform this sum when all the shapefiles intersect but not where only 2 intersects. This is a semplificate example because i have only 3 shapefiles, but potentially i could have many of them (eg. 60). I know that if i convert the shapefiles in raster, this would be an easy operation, but i would like to avoid it

Comment: I converted the shapefiles to geojson but Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post them in the question

Comment: g1, g2 and g3 are 3 different shapefiles and they contain information i need to sum in the intersection areas. I am doing those 2 operations in order to get all the areas that are common to the 3 shapefiles (intersection), where i am able to sum the attributes, and the areas that belong to only one shapefile (symmetric_difference). I miss all the areas that are common to 2 shapefiles and not to the other one and i don't know how to get them, considering that the number of shapefiles can be big (60 shapefiles) and not just 3 like in this example

Comment: yes, they are all polygon shapefiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you did not properly save `intersection` and `simmertric` an output geodataframe.  You would have to initialize `final_result` before the for loop, and concat with itself inside the for loop.

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

polys1 = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(0,0), (2,0), (2,2), (0,2)]),
                              Polygon([(2,2), (4,2), (4,4), (2,4)])])
polys2 = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(-1,-1), (1,-1), (1,1), (-1,1)]),
                              Polygon([(1,1), (3,1), (3,3), (1,3)])])
polys3 = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(1,1), (3,1), (3,3), (1,3)]),
                              Polygon([(3,3), (5,3), (5,5), (3,5)]),
                              Polygon([(6,6), (8,6),(8,8),(6,8)])])

df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys1, 'rate_cars':[10,20]})
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys2, 'rate_cars':[100,200]})
df3 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys3, 'rate_cars':[1,2,3]})

merge = pd.concat([df1,df2, df3],ignore_index=True)

out = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
for df in [df1,df2,df3]:

    #find which records dont come from the current iteration
    mask = merge.geom_equals(df)
    tmp = merge.copy()
    tmp = tmp[~mask]

    #find any non intersection features
    mask1 = tmp.intersects(df)

    #non intersectiong features
    non_inter = gpd.overlay(tmp, df, how='symmetric_difference')
    non_inter.loc[:,'total'] = non_inter.sum(axis=1)
    non_inter = non_inter.drop(['rate_cars_1', 'rate_cars_2'], axis=1)
    non_inter = non_inter[['total', 'geometry']]
    non_inter.loc[:,'grid_feature'] = 'street'
    non_inter = non_inter[['total','grid_feature','geometry']]

    #find intersections
    res_intersection = gpd.overlay(tmp, df, how='intersection')
    res_intersection.loc[:,'total'] = res_intersection.sum(axis=1)
    res_intersection = res_intersection.drop(['rate_cars_1', 'rate_cars_2'], axis=1)
    res_intersection = res_intersection[['total', 'geometry']]
    res_intersection.loc[:,'grid_feature'] = 'intersection'
    res_intersection = res_intersection[['total','grid_feature','geometry']]   

    out = pd.concat([out, res_intersection, non_inter])

out = out.drop_duplicates()
```

Where `out returns`:

```
   total  grid_feature                                           geometry
0  110.0  intersection  POLYGON ((0.00000 1.00000, 1.00000 1.00000, 1....
1  210.0  intersection  POLYGON ((1.00000 1.00000, 1.00000 2.00000, 2....
2   11.0  intersection  POLYGON ((1.00000 1.00000, 1.00000 2.00000, 2....
3  220.0  intersection  POLYGON ((2.00000 3.00000, 3.00000 3.00000, 3....
4   21.0  intersection  POLYGON ((2.00000 3.00000, 3.00000 3.00000, 3....
5   22.0  intersection  POLYGON ((3.00000 3.00000, 3.00000 4.00000, 4....
0  100.0        street  POLYGON ((-1.00000 -1.00000, -1.00000 1.00000,...
1  200.0        street  MULTIPOLYGON (((1.00000 2.00000, 1.00000 3.000...
2    1.0        street  MULTIPOLYGON (((1.00000 2.00000, 1.00000 3.000...
3    2.0        street  POLYGON ((3.00000 4.00000, 3.00000 5.00000, 5....
4    3.0        street  POLYGON ((6.00000 6.00000, 6.00000 8.00000, 8....
5   10.0        street  MULTIPOLYGON (((0.00000 1.00000, 0.00000 2.000...
6   20.0        street  MULTIPOLYGON (((2.00000 3.00000, 2.00000 4.000...
0  110.0  intersection  POLYGON ((0.00000 0.00000, 0.00000 1.00000, 1....
1  200.0  intersection  POLYGON ((-1.00000 -1.00000, -1.00000 1.00000,...
2  210.0  intersection  POLYGON ((1.00000 2.00000, 2.00000 2.00000, 2....
3  220.0  intersection  POLYGON ((2.00000 2.00000, 2.00000 3.00000, 3....
4  400.0  intersection  POLYGON ((1.00000 1.00000, 1.00000 3.00000, 3....
5  201.0  intersection  POLYGON ((1.00000 1.00000, 1.00000 3.00000, 3....
1   20.0        street  POLYGON ((2.00000 3.00000, 2.00000 4.00000, 4....
2    2.0        street  POLYGON ((3.00000 3.00000, 3.00000 5.00000, 5....
0   11.0  intersection  POLYGON ((1.00000 2.00000, 2.00000 2.00000, 2....
1   21.0  intersection  POLYGON ((2.00000 2.00000, 2.00000 3.00000, 3....
3    2.0  intersection  POLYGON ((1.00000 1.00000, 1.00000 3.00000, 3....
4   22.0  intersection  POLYGON ((3.00000 4.00000, 4.00000 4.00000, 4....
5    4.0  intersection  POLYGON ((3.00000 3.00000, 3.00000 5.00000, 5....
6    6.0  intersection  POLYGON ((6.00000 6.00000, 6.00000 8.00000, 8....
0   10.0        street  POLYGON ((0.00000 0.00000, 0.00000 2.00000, 1....
2  100.0        street  POLYGON ((-1.00000 -1.00000, -1.00000 1.00000,...
```

Comment: Yes i can also do that, but what if you have 3 shapefiles that intersect, as shown in the example i posted below my code. With the "intersection" in my code i am getting the results in the "red" area, where all the shapefiles intersect, but how would you get the sum in the "yellow" areas? Also, consider that in this example there are only 3 shapefiles but there could be a lot (60/70)

Comment: Why not just merge two of them together, so you can intersect them as shown?

Comment: Without any context to your problem and the data you are looking at, it's hard to really understand why you think all three shapefiles need to be treated separately.

Comment: I provided a link where the data could be downloaded. In any case it is not so easy, because in this example the 2 polygons inside `polys1` don't interesect and the 2 polygons inside `polys2` don't interesect, what if all the shapefiles intersect at least one shapefile (like in the example i provided below the code)?

Comment: Sorry, but I dont click on links like that.  Please make a construct an example using this [guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You can use shapely to construct your polygons that represent your problem.  Also, GIS data has physical meaning.  If you can explain the problem in words, maybe I can begin to understand what you are after.  I am still not sure what you are trying to do.  I am happy to help when you update your question.

Comment: Each shapefile represents a straight street in a city. For each city i have several streets and so several shapefiles. The value inside each shapefile is the quantity of cars per hour. My goal is to calculate the quantity of cars per hour in each street or intersection. In the streets (where there are no intersections) the quantity of cars would be equal to the quantity of cars specified in the shapefile, while in the intersections the quanity of cars would be equal to the sum of the quantity of cars in all the shapefiles that intersect there

Comment: The problem is that i don't find a way to calculate automatically the sum in the intersections when not all the shapefiles intersect. With the code i provided above, i am only able to calculate the quantity of cars where there are no intersections and where all the shapefiles intersect in one point

Comment: So, you have two problems, 1. find the number of cars that passed through an intersection, 2. find the number of cars in the streets.  For  1. you need to intersect the shapefiles and add attributes.  For 2, just need to add up the values in the input data, no intersection needed. I guess you have hourly shapefiles?

Comment: For 1.: yes, but i could have 60 shapefiles, this means that i should perform a huge number of iterations to find all the intersection between only 2 shapefiles, then all the intersections between 3 shapefiles and so on